# Transmit bitstream from USB over radio

Tags: digital-communications

I am extremely new to this and I'm learning by building stuff myself so please let me know if this is too vague and Ill elaborate if I can. Im sure this is something very simple, but cant figure out how to do it.

I have built radios before and know how to modulate a signal as ASK but now I'm trying to send a simple bitstream from a USB port to a radios input.
My idea was to use a serial program to dump bytes into the radio input signal but all the research I have done indicates using rs232 or UART or something. I have no experience with this and I dont want some protocol sticking parity bits in all over the place.
I simply want to be able to send, for example, 0x1234 as
00000001000000100000001100000100 at a baudrate of 2048.

My intention is to monitor the frequency with an sdr and then learn how to demodulate the bits from the IQ data.

Is there a simple method for doing this or something I dont know about which will prevent me?

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might be a better match for [electronics.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [PySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) - a python library for serial communications.

Comment: turns out it's best to do bitbanging over ftdi serial->ttl device to get that i want. PySerial is interesting tough, will be using it for some stuff, thanks!